# Ecto Query fetch grandchildren with condition on child

Tags: elixir, ecto

What's the best way to get all `comments` for a specific `user`'s `posts` where the `post` was published on a specific day?

I.e. `some_user.posts.comments where post.published_on == '2016-01-01'`

I'm not interested in fetching the posts as an intermediate step, just the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `join` with `assoc(post, :comments)` and then `select` only the comment:

```
from(p in Post,
  where: p.user_id == ^user.id and p.inserted_at == ^"2016-10-12T08:30:34Z",
  join: c in assoc(p, :comments),
  select: c)
```

```
iex(1)> user = Repo.get!(User, 1)
iex(2)> Repo.all from(p in Post, where: p.user_id == ^user.id and p.inserted_at == ^"2016-10-12T08:30:34Z", join: c in assoc(p, :comments), select: c)
[debug] QUERY OK source="posts" db=0.6ms
SELECT c1."id", c1."content", c1."post_id", c1."user_id", c1."inserted_at", c1."updated_at" FROM "posts" AS p0 INNER JOIN "comments" AS c1 ON c1."post_id" = p0."id" WHERE ((p0."user_id" = $1) AND (p0."inserted_at" = $2)) [1, {{2016, 10, 12}, {8, 30, 34, 0}}]

[%MyApp.Comment{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "comments">,
  content: nil, id: 1, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-10-12 08:30:42>,
  post: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :post is not loaded>,
  post_id: 1, updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-10-12 08:30:42>,
  user: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user is not loaded>,
  user_id: 1},
 %MyApp.Comment{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "comments">,
  content: nil, id: 2, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-10-12 08:39:41>,
  post: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :post is not loaded>,
  post_id: 1, updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-10-12 08:39:41>,
  user: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user is not loaded>,
  user_id: 1},
 %MyApp.Comment{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "comments">,
  content: nil, id: 3, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-10-12 08:39:42>,
  post: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :post is not loaded>,
  post_id: 1, updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-10-12 08:39:42>,
  user: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user is not loaded>,
  user_id: 1}]
```

My app above doesn't have `published_on : Ecto.Date` so I used `inserted_at : Ecto.DateTime`. Just change `inserted_at` to `published_on` and change the value to a valid type that can be cast to `Ecto.Date` by ecto and it should work with your app.